# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid on login page react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

so im new to reactnative and currently Im making a login page with react native and i got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7IT2.jpg) on my app

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>   Check the render method of 'Button'.

here is the **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Input } from './components/Input';
import { Button } from './components/Button';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Input
          placeholder='Enter your mail...'
          label='Email'
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}
          value={this.state.email}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder='Enter your password'
          label='Password'
          secureTextEntry
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
          value={this.state.password}
        />
        <Button onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}>Log In</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20
  },
});
```

and this is the *Button.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpactity} from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpactity onPress={onPress} style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.text}> { children } </Text>
        </TouchableOpactity>

    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        marginTop: 10,
        padding: 20,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#00aeef',
        borderRadius: 4,
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: '700',
        fontSize: 18,
      }
    });

export { Button };
```

any idea why is this happened to my app?
thanks

Update: i follow the solutions below, and it come up with another [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdf59.jpg)

any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Button.js you should write :

```
export default Button;
```

And your import should be :

```
import Button from './components/Button';
```

Instead of :

```
export { Button };
```

In this context is better to have `export default Button`.

Comment: Nope, not the problem

Comment: @FidriyantoRizkillah: You can refer to this snack: https://snack.expo.io/S1eeh4sm7 There is nothing wrong with exporting without default and importing using braces

Comment: @FidriyantoRizkillah: Not sure why your code is working is quite dangerous, just a piece of advice. Have fun!

Comment: @Issac : of course you can do it, but from the example in the question the file 'Button.js' should only export a Button, it's why I said 'In this context' at the end of the question.

Comment: @Pintouch: But OP is saying he is hitting exception, and you suggesting an answer that can solve the issue, right? Or you are giving an answer that is a best practice? Coz you're right, `export default` is better in this context, but I doubt is fixing the real problem

Comment: @Pintouch: Anyway, just glad that OP has solved his issue, I'm pointing out to you is because I wish to know the reason too as I'm new to RN too :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is when you import `TouchableOpactity` in your `Button.js`. It should be TouchableOpacity

Comment: i think the import is the problem, but this also corrected my code thanks sir